# Implementing Cookie Storage with angular-auth-oidc-client

Tags: angular, authentication

The angular-auth-oidc-client package uses session storage by default. The problem is our users use this app in multiple tabs/windows at the same time. Session storage requires that the user authenticates in each tab. To prevent this, I want to use cookie storage. I used [this article](https://medium.com/@arv9135/angular-10-spa-and-identity-server-4-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-with-cookie-storage-a572a8baa4ea) as a guide but once I used the custom storage I get an error in the browser when trying to authorize:

```
authWellKnownEndpoints is undefined
could not create url [null]
```

If I use the default storage, everything works as expected. Any ideas on what to do to solve this issue?

Here's the service I wrote for custom storage for reference:

```
export class AuthCookieStorageService implements AbstractSecurityStorage {
    constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService) {}

    public read(key: string): any {
        const item = this._cookieService.get(key);
        console.log('\nCookie Storage Service getting item: ', item, '\n');

        if (!!item) {
            return JSON.parse(item);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public write(key: string, value: any): void {
        const writeValue = value || null;
        this._cookieService.set(key, JSON.stringify(writeValue), undefined, undefined, undefined, true, 'Strict');
    }
}
```

### Edit

Originally I was using `ngx-cookie-service` to manage the cookies, and that seems to have been the issue. Moving to `ngx-cookie` solved the issue of not having access to certain auth data.

However, the issue now is that when I open the app in a new tab I still have to authenticate again. I can see the auth data in the cookies in the new tab, but they're apparently not being used when the app loads.

Comment: The first issue (authWellKnownEndpoints is undefined) did occur in Chrome, but in Firefox the app loaded correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue and am wondering if you ever solved this?

Comment: Are you able to fix the issue? I'm also facing the same problem. The session storage is loading with the authToken, but by then the authguard comes into play, that time session is unavailable. Consequently, it redirects to the login page.